# javafx set yAxis.setLowerBounds greater than 0

Tags: java, javafx

I have a StackedBarGraph from javafx.
I am trying to set the lower bounds to a number greater than 0.0.
I think this is a problem with StackedBarCharts.
When I try it with Barchart it will work fine.

```
// working          yAxis.setLowerBound(-10.0);
// working          yAxis.setLowerBound(0.0);
// not working      yAxis.setLowerBound(5.0);


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaGraphTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {

            stage.setTitle("Lotto Tracking Graph");

            final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
            final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
            final StackedBarChart<String,Number> bc =   new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
            Scene scene = new Scene(bc,800,600);

            yAxis.setLabel("Count");

            yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
            yAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);

 // The is the only change made

    // working          yAxis.setLowerBound(-10.0);
    // working          yAxis.setLowerBound(0.0);
    // not working      yAxis.setLowerBound(5.0);



            yAxis.setUpperBound(60);

            XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
            XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();

            Integer x, y=-6;
            for(x = 1; x<55 ; x++) {

                series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(x.toString(), x + y));
                series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(x.toString(),  y));

            };
            bc.getData().addAll(series1);
            bc.getData().addAll(series2);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setMaximized(true);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Is the source code for this class available?

Comment: hmm ... looks okay for me - the lower y at 5 just starts at 5, what exactly should be different?

Comment: My problem it the data set (Red Bars) does not show when set to 5 , the scale is correct but no bars.

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using? What OS?

Comment: hmm ... the values for both series are all negative up to the seventh or so, there's nothing to show in the positive region. So again: what do you expect? can you show a screenshot of what you see and how it should be?

Comment: and to answer the other question: the source code is in src.zip in the module path (fx11)

Comment: okay, there have been several issues with stackedBarChart: a) problems with negative values, see f.i. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8114956 and another b) not showing if y lower bound > 0 https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8097159 all marked as fixed (against fx8 or so) Right now (fx11), negative values aren't shown at all, so either a regression or a completely new bug added ..